# How to construct lists with a hierarchical structure in R?

Tags: html, xml, r

Suppose I have a character vector:

```
c("A01","A02","B0101","B0102","B02","C010101","C010102",
  "C010103","C010201","C010202","C02","C03",...)
```

and it has the following properties (Since I don't know how to interpret my question in general, I'll use some xml terms like "node", "parent" and "child"):

1. The elements of the vector are hierarchical.
2. Consider all the elements are contained in a "root node"; the leading letter of each element represents the first "child node" of the "root node", and every two adjacent numbers that follows is the "child" of the previous as well as the "parent" of the next.
3. As is shown in the vector, the length of each string is uncertain, i.e., the  number of generations within each "node" is uncertain.

Now, from the vector I want to construct a list with the following properties:

1. Each "parent node" is a list that contains other lists("child nodes").
2. The name of each list should be the same as the corresponding letter or   number within the string(see the example below).
3. The last descendant of the tree structure should be a list that has a name, but not necessarily any value.

Here's an example list based on the first 5 elements of the vector:

```
a<-list("A"=list("01"=NULL,"02"=NULL),"B"=list("01"=list("01"=NULL,"02"=NULL),"02"=NULL))  
>str(a)
List of 2
 $ A:List of 2
  ..$ 01: NULL
  ..$ 02: NULL
 $ B:List of 2
  ..$ 01:List of 2
  .. ..$ 01: NULL
  .. ..$ 02: NULL
  ..$ 02: NULL
```

I wonder if there's any R function that can generate the list I want with the vector as an input; and if no, how to write one that can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this be recursively calling a function that processes a list:

```
dat <- c("A01","A02","B0101","B0102","B02")
make.list <- function(x) {
  parent <- substr(x, 1, 2)
  remaining <- substr(x, 3, nchar(x))
  lapply(split(remaining, parent), function(y) {
    if (all(nchar(y) == 0)) NULL
    else make.list(y)
  })
}
parent <- substr(dat, 1, 1)
remaining <- substr(dat, 2, nchar(dat))
A <- lapply(split(remaining, parent), make.list)
str(A)
# List of 2
#  $ A:List of 2
#   ..$ 01: NULL
#   ..$ 02: NULL
#  $ B:List of 2
#   ..$ 01:List of 2
#   .. ..$ 01: NULL
#   .. ..$ 02: NULL
#   ..$ 02: NULL
```